# Android - How to show App logo in action bar

Tags: android, themes, graphical-logo

The theme of my application is Light. Can I display app icon in action bar without changing app style from Theme.Light to Theme.Holo.Light.

style.xml

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:logo="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
```

The styles of "EditText" and etc object more beautiful with Theme.Light, that why I don't want to change it. It is possible or I should write style for each object and change theme of application.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This works for me with Theme.Light

```
android.support.v7.app.ActionBar menu = getSupportActionBar();
menu.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
menu.setLogo(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
menu.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);
```

Answer (score 2):

The actionbar uses the android:logo attribute from manifest file. Then use setDisplayUseLogoEnabled() to set it in the ActionBar

Comment: When my application theme is "Theme.Light" and onCreate function I write getActionBar().setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true); application crashes. Did I am right understand you?

Comment: Is your code working with action bar without doing any logo related settings?

Comment: If I write in theme this `<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">` its displays logo too but whit theme which I don't want to have. And in this case I can write `getActionBar().setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true)` too. I need to know if exist any way to display logo in action bar without changing `Theme.Light` theme to `Theme.Holo.Light`?

Comment: does anyone know how in Kotlin?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
 getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_HOME |
                ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_TITLE | ActionBar.DISPLAY_HOME_AS_UP | 
                ActionBar.DISPLAY_USE_LOGO);
 getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.search_icon);
 getSupportActionBar().setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

This works well for me:

```
//show the icon
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
```